# use caching for login page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to leverage the benefit of caching. I tried both page caching and fragment caching and none worked. For page caching what i did is

development.rb and environment.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

inside controller which is responsible for showing that login page

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ::ActionView::Layouts

  attr_accessor :callback_url

  layout 'login_portal'

  caches_page :new

  def new
  end
```

this did not work. I get the error like unknown method caches_page

fragment caching

For this inside new.html.slim which is inside views/devise/sessions

```
<% cache 'new' do%>
....
<% end %>
```

but this way the above <% cache %> is also shown in the UI.

How do i use cache for my login page as it is static page ?

Comment: you're using erb syntax in slim template

Answer (score 1):

Static page caching for Action Pack is removed from core since Rails 4.0,

You need this gem

```
gem "actionpack-page_caching"
```

First you need to set page_cache_directory in your configuration file

```
config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root}/public/cached_pages"
```

then in the controller

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base
  caches_page :new
end
```

Read more here https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching

Comment: do i need to first create a directory called cached_pages for config.action_controller.page_cache_directory ?

Comment: Yes, please create a dir called cached_pages in YourRailsApp/public

Comment: I checked the docs but could not find the way to know if its working or not.

Comment: You check if there is a .html file created in the cache_directory

Comment: not created and I have refreshed the same page multiple times

Comment: new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                  users/sessions#new so I used caches_page :new in sessions_controller

Comment: The generated cache files will be like weblog/show/5.html and weblog/new.html, which match the URLs used that would normally trigger dynamic page generation... please read the doc of that gem